# My application crashes when converting an EditText/String to Integer

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I'm working on an application for my A2 Level Computer Science coursework, and have run into an error when attempting to convert an EditText to an integer.  I'm creating an application that is intended to help with managing a Scout group, and I am currently working on allowing the user to create a record containing Scout details, and insert it into a database. Here is the line that is apparently erroneous:

```
emergencyhome=Integer.parseInt(findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyHomePhone).toString());
```

And this comes up in the Logcat:

```
01-06 17:23:18.789 20899-20899/com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype, PID: 20899
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{261e7d93 VFED..CL........ 198,1096-498,1155 #7f0700dd app:id/txtEmergencyHomePhone}"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype.frmAddAScout.saveScout(frmAddAScout.java:202)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.  I've attached the code in context below.

```
package com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class frmAddAScout extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioGroup genderGroup;
    RadioGroup photoGroup;
    TextView lblError;
    TextView genderID; //This is to help with another issue that I'm in the process of solving, don't worry about it.
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frm_add_ascout);
        genderGroup=findViewById(R.id.grpGender);
        photoGroup=findViewById(R.id.grpPhotos);
        lblError=findViewById(R.id.lblError);
        genderID=findViewById(R.id.genderID);
        //Creating options for the section spinner & populating it
        List<String> sectionArray=new ArrayList<>();
        sectionArray.add("Beavers");
        sectionArray.add("Cubs");
        sectionArray.add("Scouts");
        sectionArray.add("Explorers");
        sectionArray.add("Network");
        sectionArray.add("Leaders");

        ArrayAdapter<String> sectionAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sectionArray
        );

        sectionAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner sectionItems=findViewById(R.id.spinSection);
        sectionItems.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);

        //creating options for the swimming spinner & populating it
        List<String> swimmingArray=new ArrayList<>();
        swimmingArray.add("Unable to swim");
        swimmingArray.add("Fairly confident");
        swimmingArray.add("Very confident");

        ArrayAdapter<String> swimmingAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, swimmingArray
        );

        swimmingAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner swimmingItems=findViewById(R.id.spinSwimming);
        swimmingItems.setAdapter(swimmingAdapter);
    }


    public void backToScoutMenu(View view)
    {
        Intent goBack = new Intent(frmAddAScout.this, frmScoutsMenu.class);
        startActivity(goBack);
    }


    public void saveScout(View v)
    {
        databaseHandler db;
        db=new databaseHandler(this);
        //To do: Import all IDs created thus far & check against them to ensure it's unique here

        int id = (int)(Math.random()*(9999)+1);
        String firstname;
        if (findViewById(R.id.txtForename).toString().length() > 0)
        {
            firstname=(findViewById(R.id.txtForename).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        String lastname;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtSurname).toString().length() > 0))
        {
            lastname=(findViewById(R.id.txtSurname).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        String dob;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtDateOfBirth).toString().length() > 0))
        {
            dob=(findViewById(R.id.txtDateOfBirth).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        Spinner grabSection=findViewById(R.id.spinSection);
        String section=(grabSection.getSelectedItem().toString());

        boolean sex;
        int genderselected=genderGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if (genderselected==2131165338)
        {
            sex=true; //True means male
        }
        else if (genderselected==2131165337)
        {
            sex=false;
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            genderID.setText("ID: "+ genderselected);
            return;
        }

        String address1;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtAddress1).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            address1=(findViewById(R.id.txtAddress1).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        String address2;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtAddress2).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            address2=(findViewById(R.id.txtAddress2).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        String city;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtCity).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            city=(findViewById(R.id.txtCity).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        String postcode;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtPostCode).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            postcode=(findViewById(R.id.txtPostCode).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        String religion;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtReligion).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            religion=(findViewById(R.id.txtReligion).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        String emergencyname;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyContactName).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            emergencyname=(findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyContactName).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        int emergencyhome;
        if ((HomePhone.toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            emergencyhome=Integer.parseInt(findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyHomePhone).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        int emergencymobile;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyMobilePhone).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            emergencymobile=Integer.parseInt(findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyMobilePhone).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        String emergencyemail;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyEmail).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            emergencyemail=(findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyEmail).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        String medicaldetails;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtMedicalDetails).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            medicaldetails=(findViewById(R.id.txtMedicalDetails).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        String allergies;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtAllergies).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            allergies=(findViewById(R.id.txtAllergies).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        String lasttetanus;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtLastTetanus).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            lasttetanus=(findViewById(R.id.txtLastTetanus).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        int swimmingability;
        String swimmingString=(findViewById(R.id.listSwimmingAbility).toString());
        if (swimmingString.equals("Unable to swim"))
        {
            swimmingability=0;
        }
        else if (swimmingString.equals("Fairly confident"))
        {
            swimmingability=1;
        }
        else if (swimmingString.equals("Very confident"))
        {
            swimmingability=2;
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - an unknown error has occurred.  Please try again.");
            return;
        }

        String school;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtSchool).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            school=(findViewById(R.id.txtSchool).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        boolean photos;
        int photosAllowed=photoGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if (photosAllowed==0)
        {
            photos=true; //True means male
        }
        else if (photosAllowed==1)
        {
            photos=false;
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            genderID.setText("Photo ID: "+ photosAllowed);
            return;
        }

        String moveup;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtMoveUp).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            moveup=(findViewById(R.id.txtMoveUp).toString());
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.setText("Error - please fill all necessary fields");
            return;
        }

        scoutDetails Scout=new scoutDetails(id, firstname, lastname, dob, section, sex, address1, address2, city, postcode, religion, emergencyname, emergencyhome, emergencymobile, emergencyemail, medicaldetails, allergies, lasttetanus, swimmingability, school, photos, moveup);
        db.createScout(Scout);

        backToScoutMenu(v);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `toString()` to get an integer from an EditText.
Here's how you can get an Integer from your EditText:

```
//Create and initialize your EditText
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyHomePhone);

//Get the String that's contained in the EditText
String userInput = editText.getText().toString();

//Convert the String to an Integer
int emergencyHome = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
```

If you'd like to combine all of this in one single line (like ninjas do), then here's the way to go:

```
int emergencyHome = Integer.parseInt(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyHomePhone)).getText().toString());
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 0):

If `txtEmergencyHomePhone` is an EditText, you need to get the actual text from it.

`findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyHomePhone).toString()` is wrong.

you need to use

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyHomePhone);
String text = editText.getText().toString();
```

and then parse it to int.

Comment: Really sorry, but the IDE is now giving me the error message "Cannot resolve method getText()" - I've written this:

`emergencyhome=Integer.parseInt((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyHomePhone).getText());`

Do you have any other ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: @SamOg Edited my answer. You need to do it in 2 lines.`findViewById` automatically casts the object to `EditText` now, which has a `getText()` method

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply - the only issue is, it's still crashing on this line:
`emergencyhome = Integer.parseInt(emergencyHomeString);`
Which in context looks like this:
`int emergencyhome;
        if ((findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyHomePhone).toString()).length() > 0)
        {
            EditText emergencyHomeField = (findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyHomePhone));
            String emergencyHomeString=((emergencyHomeField).getText().toString());
            emergencyhome = Integer.parseInt(emergencyHomeString);` If you have any other ideas, that would be great.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SamOg I will say it again. You **should not** use (findViewById(R.id.txtEmergencyHomePhone).toString(), it does not produce the result you think it does. The parseInt method will crash if the String is not only numbers.

Comment: I was only using that to find the length of the number - would that still cause an issue?

Comment: Never mind, it's all sorted now, thanks for your help!